# Live Updating Widget for 100+ concurrent users

Tags: python, comet, scaling, tornado

what would you use if you had to have a div box on your website that would have to be updated constantly with new HTML content from the server.

simple polling is probably not very resource inefficient - imagine also having 10'000 users and the div has to update.

what is the most efficient or elegant solution for such a problem?

are there existing widgets which contain this "autoupdate" functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [memcached](http://memcached.org/). By caching content in memory
you will reduce the number of calls to the (database?) server that generates the content.

To keep the content up to date you should use the [memcache pattern](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache.html#Pattern). A short expiration time will provide more up to date content, a long expiration time will provide better performance.